# How to parse xml response from Google Contacts API in C#

Tags: parsing, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get the Contacts List through the Google Contacts API in my C# application.

Following is the code i am using to pull the Google Contacts, but not sure on parsing the Response:

```
        OAuthGContacts _google = new OAuthGContacts();
        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(_google.AuthorizationLinkGet());

        }
        else
        {
              //Get the access token and secret.
            _google.AccessTokenGet(Request["code"]);

            if (_google.Token.Length > 0)
            {
             string   _contactResponse = _google.WebRequest(OAuthGContacts.Method.GET, "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + _google.Token, string.Empty);
             XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(_contactResponse ));
             SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
             reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Please suggest on how to parse the Response to pull the Google Contacts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse any XML response to get a Contact List in a C# application. Google's Data API provides functionality to do that. [Here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) is an .NET example. If you see the Protocol, then simply click to the .NET tab and you will see the following code

```
public static void PrintAllContacts(ContactsRequest cr)
{
  Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
  foreach (Contact entry in f.Entries)
  ....
```